# The ScreenManager on my coding doesn't work on my program

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I have a problem with my coding. I am trying to make ScreenManager work on my app. I have three button actions related to my project: a QR Code Scanner example on one screen, a checklist on one screen, and a hyperlink action button.

I am now trying to combine all three into a single .py program, with a single .kv design file. However, I have encountered a 'NoneType' error on my coding. And if I remove the Builder file, and edit the .kv file to a simple GridLayout and button, the coding works, but it will be displayed blank.

The coding is listed below.

**Test Integration.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MainMenu(Screen):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.size_hint = (0.6, 0.7)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="Are You Safe.jpeg"))

        self.greeting = Label(
            text="What's your name?",
            font_size=18,
            color='#00FFCE'
        )
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)
        self.user = TextInput(
            multiline=False,
            padding_y=(20, 20),
            size_hint=(1, 0.5)
        )

        self.window.add_widget(self.user)

        self.button = Button(
            text="NEXT",
            size_hint=(1, 0.5),
            bold=True,
            background_color='#00FFCE',
            background_normal=""
        )

        self.button.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)

        return self.window


    def callback(self, instance):
        self.greeting.text = "Hello " + self.user.text + "!"

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def checkbox_click(self, instance, value, safety):
        if value == True:
            self.ids.output_label.text = f'Well done.'
        else:
            self.ids.output_label.text = "You are recommended to acquire or purchase the missing safety equipment."

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    ...

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    ...

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('Test Integration.kv')
        screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition="SlideTransition()")
        screen_manager.add_widget(MainMenu(name="MainMenu"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(FirstScreen(name="FirstScreen"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(SecondScreen(name="SecondScreen"))
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**Test Integration.kv**

```
LogInMenu:

<LogInMenu>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
        text: "Are You Safe? \[A project by students of Temasek Polytechnic.\]"

        Button:
            text: "Mandatory Equipment Checklist."
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "FirstScreen"
                root.manager.transition = "right"
    
        Button:
            text: "QR Code Scanner"
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "SecondScreen"
                root.manager.transition = "right"
    
        Button:
            text: "Link to Our Survey."
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "ThirdScreen"
                root.manager.transition = "right"

<FirstScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "A Mandatory Safety Checklist."

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Label:
            text: "Checklist: Do you acquired all the necessary safety equipment?"
            font_size: 24
    
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
    
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety gloves with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety gloves with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety boots with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety boots with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your safety goggles with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your safety goggles with you?")
            Label:
                text: "Do you have your helmet with you?"
                font_size:16
            CheckBox:
                on_active: root.checkbox_click(self, self.active, "Do you have your helmet with you?")
    
        Label:
            id: output_label
            text: "You are recommended to acquire or purchase the missing safety equipment."
    
        Button:
            text: "Return to Main Menu."
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "LogInMenu"
                root.manager.transition = "left"

<SecondScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
        text: "QR Code Scanner."

    Button:
            text: "Return to Main Menu."
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "LogInMenu"
                root.manager.transition = "left"

<ThirdScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
        text: "A Link to Our Survey."

    Button:
       text:"Survey on feedback."
    
       on_release:
    
          # importing webbrowser module
          import webbrowser
    
          # it will open google window in your browser
          webbrowser.open('https://forms.gle/k6cfYEU1snzpykxY9')
    
    Button:
            text: "Return to Main Menu."
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "LogInMenu"
                root.manager.transition = "right"

<WindowManager>:
    LogInMenu:
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:
    ThirdScreen:
```

These are the errors I encountered:

**Result of Coding:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\Test Integration.py", line 76, in <module>
     MyMainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\Test Integration.py", line 68, in build
     Builder.load_file('Test Integration.kv')
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 372, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 483, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 593, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 696, in parse_level
     _objects, _lines = self.parse_level(
   File "C:\Users\nicho\PycharmProjects\Temasek Polytechnic MP (Software App)\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 756, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

As you can see, I don't know how to fix the 'NoneType' object TypeError.  And as mentioned earlier in the post, when I changed the .kv file's commands to a simple GridLayout and Button commands on the <FirstScreen>, <SecondScreen>, and <ThirdScreen>, and remove the Builder.load_file(Test Integration.kv) from the Test Integration.py file, the coding works, but nothing is displayed. This coding is based on my final year project.

Answer (score 0):

This is were your problem is

```
screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition="SlideTransition()")
```

You already created a WindowManager class which inherits from ScreenManager so you need to use WindowManager() instead of ScreenManager(). Also the qoutation marks must be removed

Like this

```
screen_manager = WindowManager(transition=SlideTransition())
```

Lastly to use there is a probel with how your transition code.
Insted of

```
root.manager.transition = "left"
```

It must be like this

```
root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

This tutorial might serve as a reminder https://youtu.be/H3U29kXJlBk

Comment: Hello there sir, I tried your recommendations and it still shows the "NoneType" Error is not subscriptable error. I guess I have to follow your code on YouTube and see if that is the problem.

Comment: Did code on youtube work?